# Cannot get rid of elif invalid syntax in python

Tags: python, formatting

```
def func(val):
    num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    if num>val: 
        print ("Too high!")
    return 1
    elif num: 
        print ("Too low!")
    return -1
    else: 
        print ("Got it!!")
    return 0
        ch=1
    while(ch!=0): 
        ch=func(15)
```

I keep getting the error:
   "elif num:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax" 
Is it simply a formatting issue that is causing this error message? or my code?

Comment: All your `return`s are incorrectly indented.

Answer (score 2):

`return` statements should be indented

```
def func(val):
    num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    if num>val: 
        print ("Too high!")
        return 1
    elif num: 
        print ("Too low!")
        return -1
    else: 
        print ("Got it!!")
        return 0
        ch=1
    while(ch!=0): 
        ch=func(15)
```

Comment: Thank you! I can get it to run now, but there is no output to ask me to enter a number?